# To implement a time dependent formula

Tags: python, finance

I need to find the Survival Probability of a Credi Default Swaps.
I have already implemented the Dataframe with CDS Spread and Discounting Factor.
I'm stuck in implementing the Formula for the survival probability.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yla7y.png)

The following is the data frame which I already bootstrap the US Treasury rate and Discount Factor:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4mPM.png)

The parameters are:

D(O,Tn) refers to DF [Discouning Factor]

L is 0.6

P(Tn-1) is Previous Survival Probability

DELTA tn is 1 or dt

P(Tn) is 100

Sn is cds

Kindly help to implement the formula in python.

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: Can't you do a cumulative product of (1-pdf)?